# Mi formulario en JSP no realiza la respectiva validación si no que manda la información al controlador y realice la inserción en la base de datos?

Tags: javascript, java, formularios, jsp, validación

quiero validar mi formulario de registrar usuarios en un archivo JS pero mi problema es que al yo accionar el botón no realiza la respectiva validación, si no que manda la información de los input los manda a mi controlador y realiza el proceso
Tome como guía el siguiente video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUJr5Itz8kY&t=185s
Adjuntos codigo de mi JSP y mi archivo validar.js

Ruta en jsp

```
<script src="js/validaciones/Validar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Formulario en jsp

```
<form name="registrate" action="Usuario" class="appointment-form ftco-animate"  onsubmit="return validar()">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="textNombre" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre" required>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="textApellido" placeholder="Apellido" id="apellido" required>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="textIdentificacion" placeholder="Cedula" id="identificacion" required>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="textFecha" placeholder="Fecha Nacimiento" onfocus="(this.type = 'date')" id="nacimiento" required>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="textCiudad" placeholder="Ciudad" id="ciudad" required>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="textCorreo" placeholder="Correo" id="correo" required>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="textTelefono" placeholder="Telefono" id="telefono" required>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="textUsuario" placeholder="Usuario" id="usuario" required>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="textContrasena" placeholder="Contraseña" id="contrasena" required>
                                <select name="textRol" class="form-control" class="selectFormulario" id="rol" required>
                                    <option>Selecciona tu rol</option>
                                    <option value="1" class="selectR">Cliente</option>
                                    <option value="2" class="selectR">Empleado</option>
                                </select>                 
                            </div> 
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary py-3 px-4" value="Registrar">
                                <input type="hidden" value="1" name="opcion">
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Archivo validar.js

```
function validar() {
var nombre, apellido, identificacion, nacimiento, ciudad, correo, telefono, usuario, contrasena, rol, expresion;
nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
apellido = document.getElementById('apellido').value;
identificacion = document.getElementById('identificacion').value;
nacimiento = document.getElementById('nacimiento').value;
ciudad = document.getElementById('ciudad').value;
correo = document.getElementById('correo').value;
telefono = document.getElementById('telefono').value;
usuario = document.getElementById('usuario').value;
contrasena = document.getElementById('contrasena').value;
rol = document.document.getElementById('rol').value;

expresion = /\w+@\w+\.+[a-z]/;


if (nombre === "" || apellido === "" || identificacion === "" || nacimiento === "" || ciudad === "" || correo === "" || telefono === "" || usuario === "" || contrasena === "" || rol === "") {
    alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios");
    return false;
}
else if (nombre.length > 30) {
    alert("El nombre es muy largo");
    return false;
}
else if (apellido.length > 30) {
    alert("El apellido es muy largo");
    return false;
}
else if (identificacion.length > 12) {
    alert("La identificacion es muy largo");
    return false;
}

else if (correo.length > 50) {
    alert("El correo es muy largo");
    return false;
}
else if (telefono.length > 10) {
    alert("El telefono contiene 10 digitos");
    return false;
}
else if (usuario.length > 30 || contrasena.length > 30) {
    alert("El usuario o la contraseña superan los 30 caracteres");
    return false;
}

else if (isNaN(telefono)) {
    alert("El teléfono ingresado no es un número");
    return false;
}
else if (!expresion.test(correo)) {
    alert("El correo no es valido");
    return false;
}
```

}

¿Quisiera saber que esta fallando o que esta mal en mi código o si hace falta algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te recomiendo modificar la logica de tu formulario para que sea de la siguiente manera

```
<form name="registrate" action="javascript:validar()" class="appointment-form ftco-animate" >
```

y al final de la funcion validar, si todo esta ok hagas una peticion Ajax enviando el formulario

tambien debes cambiar

```
 rol = document.document.getElementById('rol').value;
```

por

```
 rol = document.getElementById('rol').value;
```

Comment: Me podrías ayudar a como realizar esa petición, lo ideal es que esos datos lleguen a mi servlet

Comment: pero primero debes comprobar que tu funcion de validar es efectiva. luego podrias obtener los valores y almacenarlos en un objeto, despues hacer un fetch o un ajax a el endpoint agregando el objeto en el body de la peticion

Comment: Amigo no funciono la validación al oprimir el botón no me manda ninguna alerta obviamente probando como por ejemplo que el nombre pase los 30 caracteres

Comment: y la consola te envia algun error?

Comment: claro, en rol = document.document.getElementById('rol').value; tienes 2 veces document

Comment: que error tan bobo jajajajaja pero de los errores se aprende muchas gracias amigo

Comment: te recomiendo que siempre coloques todos tus codigos dentro de try catch finally asi puedes debuggear mas facilmente